# Fast algorithm for L1 distance between rank-1 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity

I have two rank-1 matrices $A = a_1 a_2^T$ and $B = b_1 b_2^T$, where $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{R}^N$ are vector-columns. I am interested in a fast way to compute the L1 distance between $A$ and $B$: $\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N |A_{ij} - B_{ij}|$. Straightforwardly computing A and B and performing element-wise operations requires $O(N^2)$ time and memory.

For $L_2$ distance, however, there exists an $O(N)$ solution:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N (A_{ij} - B_{ij})^2 = ||a_1||_2^2 \cdot||a_2||_2^2 + ||b_1||_2^2 \cdot||b_2||_2^2 - 2 <a_1, b_1>\cdot<a_2, b_2>$$

where $<\cdot, \cdot>$ is a scalar product.

Is there an O(N) algorithm for L1? Or at least some approximations/bounds?

Comment: I would suggest it's probably helpful to consider some specific cases and try to generalize. Note for instance that if all vectors have positive entries, $a_1 > b_1$, and $a_2 > b_2$, then this distance can be computed as 
$$
\left(\sum_{i = 1}^N a_1(i)\right)\left(\sum_{i = 1}^N a_2(i)\right) - \left(\sum_{i = 1}^N b_1(i)\right)\left(\sum_{i = 1}^N b_2(i)\right).
$$
I suspect that this could be generalized by accounting for the signs of all entries of $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ and all comparisons between corresponding entries of $a_1,b_1$ and $a_2,b_2$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann It seems to me that determining whether $a_{1, i} a_{2, j}$ is bigger than $b_{1, i} b_{2, j}$ or not will cost $O(N^2)$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I recommended that approach. I don't think I'll have time to flesh out the details, but I suspect that you or another answerer could use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If bounds are enough, you can compare with the Schatten 1-norm. Citing
[Equivalence inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201845/equivalence-of-entrywise-1-norm-and-schatten-1-norm), we have

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n}\|C\| \leq \|C\|_* \leq \|C\|
\end{equation}
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $\ell_1$ norm on the entries of $C$ and $\|C\|_* $ is the Schatten 1-norm (sum of the singular values of $C$).

You can get the singular values as follows:
\begin{align}
A-B
&=
a_1 a_2^\top
-
b_1 b_2^\top\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & -b_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_2^\top \\
b_2^\top
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Find the QR-decomposition of these matrices to get
\begin{align}
A-B
&=
Q_1R_1 R_2^\top Q_2^\top
\end{align}
Then you can find the SVD of the $2\times 2$ matrix $R_1 R_2^\top$ to get the singular values.

Comment: Not a very useful bound, but now I think that there isn't any fast way of doing this.

Comment: The geometry of $\ell_2$ really helps and simplifies things. $\ell_1$ really is a challenge. I considered some other possibilities, but it would really depend on the vectors involved. If you have additional information, it may be possible to do something better.